# Usage of pointer in strchr in C Programming

Tags: c

I have the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char string[30],ch,*chp;
    printf("Enter Text below:");
    gets(string);
    printf("\n Character to find:");
    ch=getchar();
    chp=strchr(string,ch);
    if(chp)
        printf("Character %c found in string",ch);
    else
        printf("Character %c not found in string",ch);
    getche();
}
```

i know chp is pointer in this program , but in the if statement , the chp is not compared to any pointer , but how this if statment is executed , please help to understand this program.

Comment: an `if` like that is the same as saying `if(chp!=NULL)`

Comment: By the way:  **never use `gets()`.**  It has no way of keeping someone from, say, entering a thousand characters and overflowing your buffer, which will typically cause all kinds of wackiness to ensue -- possibly including someone taking control of your machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (pointer)` is equivalent to `if (pointer != NULL)`.

Answer (score 3):

The statement `if(chp)` is equivalent to `if(chp != NULL)`.  According to [this documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr), strchr "Returns a pointer to the first occurrence of character in the C string str.  If the character is not found, the function returns a null pointer."  So the statement `if(chp)` is true when a character was found.

Comment: Hm, wondering about the downvote.  Is there something I should change or clarify?

Comment: You should change the `==` in `if(chp == NULL)` to `!=` because the `if` is true when the pointer isn't `NULL`.

Comment: Sorry, typo.  That was the reason for the downvote?  Wow, tough crowd.

Comment: I didn't downvote, actually. Just trying to understand the people who did. This seemed the only problem in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` keyword in C check if its expression is not equal to 0. So

```
if (chp)
```

is equivalent to

```
if (chp != 0)
```

and in general in C there is an equivalence between the `NULL` and `0`, so

```
if (chp != NULL)
```

Note that the `if` was defined in that way because C doesn't have a proper boolean type. Often languages with a proper boolean types like *C#* and *Java* don't permit the use of `if (chp)` where `chp` isn't of boolean type. *C++* is an exception and for historical reasons (in the end it's a direct descendant of C) is like C. *Javascript* is more complex. `if (something)` is "activated" if something is `true` or (not-`0`, not-empty string, not-`null` and not `undefined`).

Answer (score 1):

When comparing pointers,

```
if(chp)
```

is the same as

```
if(chp != NULL) // null pointer
```

or

```
if(chp != 0)   // also null pointer
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing is checking to see if the pointer is not a `NULL` pointer. Recall that `NULL` is the memory address 0, defined as:

```
( ( void * ) 0 )
```

... and hence the following is equivalent:

```
if ( NULL ) <=> if ( false ) <=> if ( 0 )
```

Note that any non-zero value in C is considered `true`, only 0 is `false`. Hence, a *valid* memory address will always be `true`.

Conclusively, the statement of `if ( pointer )` is equivalent to `if ( pointer != NULL )`.